# Tried setting static ip

Tags: static-ip

I tried to set a static ip using the method below, but it didn't work. So on reboot I changed the settings back, disabled networking and reenabled dhcpcd but now I don't get any ip. Can anyone help??

Network Interfaces method

Configure a static network adddress on your Pi in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.1.1.30
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.1.1.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 10.1.1.31
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.1.1.1
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

address is the address from the command above (or another unused address on the same network),
netmask 255.255.255.0 corresponds to network size/24.
gateway is the address of your router (or gateway).

You can also specify dns-nameservers, but this is generally not necessary.
The broadcast is automatically derived from address and netmask and need not be specified.
For more detail see https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

You can set either or both eth0 or wlan0

Then disable the DHCP client daemon and switch to standard Debian networking:

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd
sudo systemctl enable networking
```

Reboot for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem only 30 minutes ago and fixed it this way:

Open /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

There you can set the IP address as well:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.1.1.30/24
static routers=10.1.1.1
```

After a reboot, I had the IP address I wanted for the RPi.